# How to download folders(including files) locally in zip format from assets folder?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on an Angular project where I have multiple SVG icons that are stored in the assets folder, there are multiple files in every folder and I want to download all of them as a `.zip` file on a button click.

I can download a single file(SVG icon) using

```
window.open('assets/icons/user interface/download.svg', '_blank');
```

but I want to download all folders (including files in it) in zip, so anyone has an idea how can I achieve this with or without using `jsZip-util`?

Comment: The client sends a request. The backend has to zip all files and respond with this zip file. What backend do you use?

Comment: @ThomasSablik actually, all folders & files are in my angular project's `assets` folder, and that what I want to download.

Comment: That's not possible. Your backend has to support it. Currently you can just create this zip file and copy it into your assets folder.

Comment: I am not using any backend at this time, I am working on just the front end, so I have icons set which I show on a page, and I want to download all those icons when I publish my website. is there any other workaround?

Comment: No, if you need backend logic in your application you need a backend. If you don't have a backend you have to create a zip file and provide it in your assets folder. The angular dev server doesn't support such logic.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I just want to ask, as I can download a single file from the assets folder then why angular don't support multiple file download?

Comment: There is no _"multiple file download"_ in web. You can always just download one file. It's not possible to send or download folders in web. Of course, you can start multiple downloads with one action but each download contains one file. If you want to zip multiple files and download one zip file you have to implement a logic for this. You can add a button that starts one download for each file separately but that's probably not what you want. That's very frustrating for more than 10 files. Here you can find more details about [angular dev server](https://angular.io/cli/serve)

Comment: @RageshPikalmunde does your client side know the names of every file in the assets folder you want to download? If so, doing this is definitely possible.